# Python 'requests' module and encoding?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am doing a simple POST request using the requests module, and testing it against [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/)

```
import requests

url      = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
params   = {'apikey':'666666'}
sample   = {'sample': open('test.bin', 'r')}

response = requests.post( url, files=sample, params=params, verify=False)
report_info = response.json()
print report_info
```

I have an issue with the encoding. It is not using `application/octet-stream` and so the encoding is not correct. From the headers, I see:

```
{
  u'origin': u'xxxx, xxxxxx', 
  u'files': {
               u'sample': u'data:None;base64,qANQR1DBw..........
```

So, I get `data:None` instead of `data:application/octet-stream` when I try with `curl`. The file size and encoding is incorrect.

How can I force or check that it is using `application/octet-stream`?

Answer (score 1):

Sample taken from http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

```
>>> import json
>>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
>>> payload = {'some': 'data'}
>>> headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

You might want to change the `headers` to

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'}
response = requests.post( url, files=sample, params=params, verify=False,
             headers = headers)
```

Comment: Thanks @thefourtheye for the suggestion, and while that does add the correct text to the header, it doesn't change the encoding. The file is still getting encoded incorrectly. It is as if python-requests is not recognising the file type correctly and so it doesn't encode correctly and it doesn't add the 'application/octet-stream' correctly.

Comment: Using python requests: `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=9e13cb8a968a49c2b7c8781e701d2c13'`. Using curl: `Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------d0f3782a702ecbd9`. Why is it different?

Comment: The boundary string is pseudo-random; as long as you're consistent within the same HTTP request, it's not a problem.